# Notify data was inserted into the table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Is there any way to notify working console application (call certain method) in case of any rows were added in the SQL Server 2012 DB table from anywhere?

Comment: From anywhere. From another application for example.

Comment: Don't really want to implement scheduled observing of the table.

Comment: can't you use triggers? say, on INSERT, execute some code that posts some notification - hard to be more specific without some more info..

Comment: I updated the question, as this is a legitimate request.  Also updated for Bogdan as that is the correct answer.  Service Broker is usually implemented to do this (which is it's own hairy monster).  You're looking for a Messaging System; RabbitMQ is another I believe, which I've never used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) One solution is to use Query Notification.
Quote:

> Built upon the Service Broker infrastructure, query notifications
>   allow applications to be notified when data has changed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/using-and-monitoring-sql-2005-query-notification/

2) Another solution could be

- a simple AFTER INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE trigger that call sp_trace_generateevent
- plus an extended events session which intercept `user_event` event (see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878264.aspx))
- plus XEvent API > Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq.dll, QueryableXEventData (see [demo](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/extended_events/archive/2011/07/20/introducing-the-extended-events-reader.aspx))